# Configure yum to install private builded rpm

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I need to install some RPMS that I build myself into RHEL8.3. I create the RPMS than add them to the iso image of red hat. I add them under BaseOS directory and when red hat is installed I mount the image and configure the /etc/yum.repos.d/something.repo as shown below.

```
[InstallMedia]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3.0
enabled=1
baseurl=file:///mnt/old_valid/BaseOS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
mediaid=None
metadata_expire=-1
gpgcheck=1
cost=500
```

That works OK I can run the yum update and see that everything is OK. When I try to install my private build rpm  I get

`Error: Unable to find a match: svr_common`  even though the binary is there.

I try to install it by giving the full path of the rpm under the mounted directory and **that works**.

`yum install /mnt/old_valid/BaseOS/Packages/svr_common-0.0-10000.x86_64.rpm`

It seems that there is something else that I need to configure in the repo but not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you point `yum` to a repository it doesn't  traverse the repository in search of  *.rpm files, it initially only tries to access the repository meta data.

Those meta data files provide yum with the overview of what packages are available in that repo (and more) and make yum operations much more expedient.

After making changes to an existing repo or when you create a new repo for your custom RPM files, you need update/generate the repo meta data, because otherwise yum won't detect those changes.

You need to install the `createrepo` package and then use the identical createrepo command for that.

```
cd /mnt/old_valid/BaseOS
createrepo --database /mnt/old_valid/BaseOS
```

Additional flags like the `--update` can speed up createrepo operations on existing repo's where only few changes were made.